# UVa_11151(Longest Palindrome)

Tags: string, algorithm

Does anybody know why the following algorithm works for finding the longest palindrome in a given string?
Find the Longest Common Subsequence(substring) of the string and its reverse. The result is the Longest Palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bolo!
But in your string lcs of the string and its reverse is either 1234A4321 or 1234B4321 which is a palindrome. A palindrome is a common subsequence for a string and its reverse, but I don't know why a (longest) common subsequence is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the statement is false.  Take the string 012310.  Its reverse is 013210.  The longest common substrings of those two strings are 01 and 10, neither of which is a palindrome.  The only palindromes in the original string are the trivial substrings of length 1.